# retrieve tweets for a given keyword in twitter4j

Tags: java, real-time, twitter4j

I am new with `twitter4j`. Just wondering, how to get "a time of period tweets" from twitter. As the `twitter4j` only can get a minimum mount of tweet.

Say, I'd like to get the last 2 weeks tweets of keyword "iphone5", how would I get these by using `twitter4j`.

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your question. Refer:[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: for example, in twitter4j, you can query() a keyword to search tweets, but it only return the lastest ones with limited number each time. so if i want to get all tweets which have keyword -"ipad mini" for the last two weeks, how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

There have been thousands of "iphone5" tweets in the past hour.  That's already going to be more tweets than you're allowed to get through the search API in bulk before you hit the limit.  Getting all the tweets in the past two weeks for a popular topic is going to be out of the question.  You'll have to narrow your search so you don't have to make so many requests (you can only get 100 tweets at a time with a query).

One other thing you might consider is getting the 1000 latest tweets on a topic every few minutes and storing them locally.  That way you can go back to your own cache if you need historical data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

    for (int page = 1; page <= 10; page++) {
        System.out.println("\nPage: " + page);
        Query query = new Query("#iPhone5");
        query.setRpp(100); // set tweets per page to 100
        query.setPage(page);
        QueryResult qr = twitter.search(query);
        List<Tweet> qrTweets = qr.getTweets();

        // break out of the loop early if there are no more tweets
        if(qrTweets.size() == 0) break;

        for(Tweet t : qrTweets) {
            System.out.println(t.getId() + " - " + t.getCreatedAt() + ": " + t.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ♦ Do u know where i can find the API of getting the 100 tweets .. thanks

Comment: @WM. Yes, see the example code I posted.  It gets 1000 tweets in a loop using Twitter4J.  Check out how the Query object is set up and called inside the loop to get 100 tweets at a time.

Comment: ♦ what packages should I include? I included the 4j package..but its not compiling!

Comment: You need `twitter4j-core-2.2.6.jar` on your classpath.  Based on your stack trace, you might also need something from Google App Engine.  You'll need to post it as a separate question.

Comment: How to remove duplicate tweets?

Comment: @BilltheLizard : I have gone through Twitter API docs, but i couldnt understand the meaning of "page". Could you please help me out ? For Example: Is it ensured that for page = 2, the tweets will be older than what were present in page = 1 ?